# Getting one record from db instead of multiples records

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I've got an `item` table having `type` and `brand` columns.

I want to get a single record against this query and it returns multiple records:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name FROM brand a
INNER JOIN item b ON a.id = b.brand
WHERE b.type = '2';
```

I have two records saved for `b.type = '2'`, but I want to get only one.

Comment: Just any one of the two at random?

Comment: Please read [mcve], then explain which record you want to keep.

Comment: yes i just want to populate dropdownlist dynamically @JacobH

Comment: Are you just looking for a `GROUP BY`? Please give a little more detail about your issue and your expected output. Sample data would help a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have duplicate records then use `DISTINCT`, maybe something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.name
FROM brand a
INNER JOIN item b ON a.id = b.brand
WHERE b.type = '2';
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `LIMIT 1` at the end, it will return the first record:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name FROM brand a
INNER JOIN item b ON a.id = b.brand
WHERE b.type = '2'
LIMIT 1;
```